# String a Datetime en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

Tengo una columna que viene desde un Excel con este tipo de campos, aqui os dejo una muestra:

[image: Muestra de la columna]

| FECHA_ENVIO |
| --- |
| NULL |
| Thu Mar 18 10:08:29 CET 2021 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| 20210620 |
| 20210605 |
| 20210601 |
| NULL |
| Fri Apr 16 00:00:00 CEST 2021 |
| 20210628 |

Las fechas en la columna tienen los siguientes formatos:

- NULL
- DiaSemana Mes Dia Hora CET Año
- DiaSemana Mes Dia Hora CEST Año
- YYYYMMDD

Tengo que decir que la columna esta en formato STRING, pero yo la querria en formato DATE TIME.

Los datos vienen así de mal porque vienen de un cliente automatizados y los tengo que cambiar al ser enviados al Datawarehouse. He probado CONVERT pero solo me transforma los que estan en 'YYYYMMDD', el problema es transformar los campos que estan escritos a modo de "Fri Mar 22 Hora CET Año".

No se me ocurre una manera de transformar los datos de esta manera igual que los de YYYYMMDD.

Un saludo!

Comment: Bienvenido Evovan a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo "acá está mi tarea, resuélvanmela" no suelen ser bien recibidas. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): muestra que intentaste/investigaste hasta ahora y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste para resolver el problema. A la comunidad le gusta mucho ayudar a quienes realmente se esfuerzan por aprender.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho tienes razón, por eso después de revisar la edición borre el comentario. Igual pienso que hay veces que la gente no sabe como resolver un problema, y por lo tanto no tiene un intento de solución que compartir.

Comment: Obviamente que después de la edición hecha por @Evovan me parece que la pregunta tiene que ser reabierta, me parece totalmente claro el problema.

Comment: @nachospiu, si creo que es justo reabrirla

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes chequear todos los posibles formatos de fecha que tienes en el campo fecha_envio y luego utilizar un `CASE` para convertir cada formato de fecha_envio en un formato que `convert()` reconozca. Yo utilicé la longitud de la cadena para distinguir los distintos formatos (hago un `trim()` para asegurarme de que no haya espacios al principio y al final de la cadena).

Según tu pregunta tienes 3 tipos de formato de fecha (contemplando que la misma puede ser nula):

- DiaSemana Mes Dia Hora CET Año.
- DiaSemana Mes Dia Hora CEST Año.
- YYYYMMDD.

Para el primer y segundo caso utilizo la función `substring()` para obtener las partes de la fecha por separado y poder construir un formato de fecha que la función `convert()` reconozca como válido (utilizo la función `concat()` para concatenar las partes de la fecha).

Luego deejecuto la función `convert()`.

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN LEN(trim(fecha_envio)) = 29 THEN
               CONVERT(datetime, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 9, 2), ' ', SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 5, 3), ' ', SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 26, 4), ' ', SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 12, 8)))
        WHEN LEN(trim(fecha_envio)) = 28 THEN
               CONVERT(datetime, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 9, 2), ' ', SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 5, 3), ' ', SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 25, 4), ' ', SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 12, 8)))
        WHEN LEN(trim(fecha_envio)) = 8  THEN 
               CONVERT(datetime, trim(fecha_envio))
        ELSE
               NULL
   END AS fecha_envio_datetime
   
FROM t;
```

Para realizar pruebas (con esta query puedes chequear que el formato de fecha sea correcto):

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN LEN(trim(fecha_envio)) = 29 THEN
               CONCAT(SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 9, 2), ' ', SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 5, 3), ' ', SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 26, 4), ' ', SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 12, 8))
        WHEN LEN(trim(fecha_envio)) = 28 THEN
               CONCAT(SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 9, 2), ' ', SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 5, 3), ' ', SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 25, 4), ' ', SUBSTRING(trim(fecha_envio), 12, 8))
        WHEN LEN(trim(fecha_envio)) = 8  THEN 
               trim(fecha_envio)
        ELSE
               NULL
   END AS fecha_envio_formateada
   
FROM t;
```

Salida de la query de pruebas (con los datos de ejmplo de la pregunta):

| fecha_envio_formateada |
| --- |
| NULL |
| 18 Mar 2021 10:08:29 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| 20210620 |
| 20210605 |
| 20210601 |
| NULL |
| 16 Apr 2021 00:00:00 |
| 20210628 |

Comment: Muchas gracias nachospiu :) ME gusta tu query como la has tratado, pero me sale este error "Error al convertir una cadena de caracteres en fecha y/u hora". He intentado hacer convert a formato DATE pero también me salta.

Comment: De nada @Evovan! Evidentemente hay alguna fecha que no ha quedado con un formato correcto. Agregué una query para que veas el formato en que queda cada fecha antes de convertirla. Deberías tratar de encontrar la fecha que falla (puedes comentar partes de CASE para ver cual falla) y luego tratar de encontrar que fila o filas son.

Comment: Revisa también que una cadena con este formato "18 Mar 2021 10:08:29" la convierta bien `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '18 Mar 2021 10:08:29')`.

Comment: ¿Que versión de sql server estás utilizando?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que si vas a insertar campos de fechas en una columna en SQL siempre sea de tipo Date y también que en el Excel a ser posible se lleve una misma estructura.
Sería algo así si quieres convertir todo a un único formato:

```html
WITH Fechas(Col) As
(
SELECT '02-04-2021' UNION ALL
SELECT '2021'-04-12'
)
SELECT Fecha_Envio,
       CONVERT(date, Fecha_Envio,
       CASE WHEN Fecha_Envio LIKE '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' then 110 
            WHEN Fecha_Envio LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]' then 120
        END
        )
FROM Fechas
```